# Multiple Objects Firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following database in Firebase:

```
Root Categories/ID/{text:Item1 AL:Item 2 TEXT:Item 3 ...}
```

I have the following code to get the Items that I want ".text" or the one that has a previous Text:

```
this.categories = af.database.list('/categories/' + this.ID);
this.categories.subscribe(categories => console.log(categories));
this.categories.subscribe(
categories => {
    categories.map(categories =>
       console.log(categories.text),

    )
});'
```

Console.log returns exactly what I want but when I retrieve `{{categories}}` in the HTML file it returns `Object` Object

Someone know how to solve it? Sorry for my ignorance I am a total beginner.

Comment: try by assigning `categories = JSON.parse(categories)` and try checking your type of `categories` using `typeOf(categories)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try and print just `{{categories}}` this is expected behavior, since `categories` seem to be an object. If you would wish to look at the `categories` as such, you'd need to add the `json` pipe:

```
{{categories | json}}
```

But I suspect that is not what you want. You need to use the properties to show each property of `categories`, for example:

```
{{categories.text}}
```

---

If `categories` is an Array, ignore the code above, but the json pipe will work in this case as well. If `categories` is an array, then you'd need to iterate the array and then print the properties you want from each object, e.g

```
<div *ngFor="let cat of categories">
  {{cat.text}}
</div>
```

If you want to pick just some certain values, you can do it inside map and assign the values to an new array, for example:

```
categoriesText: string[] = [];

this.categories.subscribe(
 categories => {
   categories.map(categories => {
      console.log(categories.text)
      this.categoriesText.push(categories.text); // push values to new array
   });
 });
```

Then you can iterate that array:

```
<div *ngFor="let cat of categoriesText">
  {{cat}} <!-- here no property name as it's only a string array -->
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Perfect. Worked exactly as I expected. Thanks a lot